# initializing PageObjects using PageFactory

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber, appium

I'am trying to launch parallel execution of tests with testng,cucumber and appium but I have an error on my second thread because of my method1 of initElements in my BasePage but when I use Method2 that works fine. see code below and logs
Can you help me please? Thank you in advance.
BaseMobile:

```
public class BaseMobile {

protected static AppiumDriver driver = new AndroidDeviceA().getDriver();
TestUtils utils = new TestUtils();
public final static Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger();
//Method1
public static <T extends BaseMobile> T instanceOf(Class<T> clazz) {

    return PageFactory.initElements(driver, clazz);
}
```

}
Method2:

```
public BaseMobile(){
this.driver = new AndroidDeviceA().getDriver();
PageFactory.initElements(new AppiumFieldDecorator(this.driver), this);
}
```

Class AndroidDeviceA:

```
public class AndroidDeviceA {

private static ThreadLocal<AppiumDriver> driver = new ThreadLocal<>();
TestUtils utils = new TestUtils();

public AppiumDriver getDriver() {
    return driver.get();
}

public void setDriver(AppiumDriver driver2) {
    driver.set(driver2);
}

public void initializeDriver() throws Exception {
    AppiumDriver driver = null;

    if (driver == null) {
        try {
            utils.log().info("initializing Appium driver");
            driver = new AndroidDriver(new AppiumServer().getServer().getUrl(), new UiAutomatorOptions().getUiAutomatorOptionsMobile());

            if (driver == null) {
                throw new Exception("driver is null. ABORT!!!");
            }
            utils.log().info("Driver is initialized");
            utils.log().info("session"+ driver.getSessionId());
            this.driver.set(driver);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            utils.log().fatal("Driver initialization failure. ABORT !!!!" + e.toString());
            throw e;
        }
    }

}
```

}

ClassSteps:

```
@When("User click on debug mode")
public void user_click_on_debug_mode() {
    instanceOf(StartScreenBorne.class).clickOnDebugMode();

    //new StartScreenBorne().clickOnDebugMode();
}
```

CucumberRunner:

```
public class RunnerBase {
private static ThreadLocal<TestNGCucumberRunner> testNGCucumberRunner = new ThreadLocal<>();

public static TestNGCucumberRunner getRunner(){
    return testNGCucumberRunner.get();
}

private static void setRunner(TestNGCucumberRunner testNGCucumberRunner1){
    testNGCucumberRunner.set(testNGCucumberRunner1);
}

@Parameters({"platformName", "udid", "deviceName", "systemPort",
        "chromeDriverPort"})
@BeforeClass(alwaysRun = true)
public void setUpClass(String platformName, String udid, String deviceName, @Optional("Android") String systemPort,
                       @Optional("Android") String chromeDriverPort) throws Exception {

    ThreadContext.put("ROUTINGKEY", platformName + "_" + deviceName);
    System.out.println(
            "Current Thread ID: "
                    + Thread.currentThread().getId());
    GlobalParams params = new GlobalParams();
    params.setPlatformName(platformName);
    params.setUDID(udid);
    params.setDeviceName(deviceName);
    params.setSystemPort(systemPort);
    params.setChromeDriverPort(chromeDriverPort);
    new AppiumServer().startServer();
    new AndroidDeviceA().initializeDriver();
    new AndroidDeviceA().getDriver().manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofSeconds(40));
    setRunner(new TestNGCucumberRunner(this.getClass()));

}

@Test(groups = "cucumber", description = "Runs Cucumber Scenarios", dataProvider = "scenarios")
public void scenario(PickleWrapper pickle, FeatureWrapper cucumberFeature) throws Throwable {
    getRunner().runScenario(pickle.getPickle());
}

@DataProvider
public Object[][] scenarios() {
    return getRunner().provideScenarios();
}

@AfterClass(alwaysRun = true)
public void tearDownClass() {
    AndroidDeviceA driverManager = new AndroidDeviceA();
    if(driverManager.getDriver() != null){
        driverManager.getDriver().quit();
        driverManager.setDriver(null);
    }
    AppiumServer serverManager = new AppiumServer();
    if(serverManager.getServer() != null){
        serverManager.getServer().stop();
    }
    if(testNGCucumberRunner != null){
        getRunner().finish();
    }
}
```

}

Logs:

Suite > R52N102P7GJ STANDARD_ERROR
Jun 07, 2022 10:28:45 PM net.masterthought.cucumber.ReportParser parseJsonFiles
INFO: File 'C:\Users\users\AppData\Local\Temp\cucumber8938908637014613434.json' contains 1 features

Suite > R9WM91REZCJ > com.runners.MyPixel3TestNGRunnerTest > scenario[0]("Create an order with formula product", "Optional[non reg Borne]") FAILED
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchSessionException: Session ID is null. Using WebDriver after calling quit()?
Build info: version: '4.1.2', revision: '9a5a329c5a'
System info: host: 'DESKTOP-N3FD63R', ip: '192.168.1.13', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '15.0.2'
Driver info: io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver
Command: [null, findElement {using=id, value=button_splashscreen_debug}]
Capabilities {appium:androidInstallTimeout: 180000, appium:app: C:\Users\users\Documents\ap..., appium:appActivity: com.tabesto.kiosk.ui.start...., appium:appPackage: com.tabesto.kiosk.debug, appium:appWaitDuration: 90000, appium:appWaitForLaunch: true, appium:autoGrantPermissions: true, appium:automationName: UiAutomator2, appium:chromedriverPort: 11000, appium:databaseEnabled: false, appium:desired: {androidInstallTimeout: 180000, app: C:\Users\users\Documents\ap..., appActivity: com.tabesto.kiosk.ui.start...., appPackage: com.tabesto.kiosk.debug, appWaitDuration: 90000, appWaitForLaunch: true, autoGrantPermissions: true, automationName: UiAutomator2, chromedriverPort: 11000, deviceName: Galaxy Tab A, eventTimings: true, nativeWebScreenshot: true, newCommandTimeout: 120, noReset: true, platformName: android, systemPort: 10000, udid: R52N102P7GJ, uiautomator2ServerLaunchTimeout: 90000}, appium:deviceApiLevel: 30, appium:deviceManufacturer: samsung, appium:deviceModel: SM-T510, appium:deviceName: R52N102P7GJ, appium:deviceScreenDensity: 240, appium:deviceScreenSize: 1200x1920, appium:deviceUDID: R52N102P7GJ, appium:eventTimings: true, appium:javascriptEnabled: true, appium:locationContextEnabled: false, appium:nativeWebScreenshot: true, appium:networkConnectionEnabled: true, appium:newCommandTimeout: 120, appium:noReset: true, appium:pixelRatio: 1.5, appium:platformVersion: 11, appium:statBarHeight: 36, appium:systemPort: 10000, appium:takesScreenshot: true, appium:udid: R52N102P7GJ, appium:uiautomator2ServerLaunchTimeout: 90000, appium:viewportRect: {height: 1812, left: 0, top: 36, width: 1200}, appium:warnings: {}, appium:webStorageEnabled: false, platformName: android}
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:145)
at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.execute(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:180)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:558)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ElementLocation$ElementFinder$2.findElement(ElementLocation.java:162)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ElementLocation.findElement(ElementLocation.java:60)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:382)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:374)
at pages.mobile.kiosk.BaseMobile.clickOnDebugMode(BaseMobile.java:53)
at steps.moble.kiosk.StartScreenSteps.user_click_on_debug_mode(StartScreenSteps.java:32)
at ?.User click on debug button

Comment: What if you run tests sequentially? Does everything run fine in that case?

Comment: Everything run fine sequentially and in parallel with method2

Comment: @AlexeyR. I added more code, can you check please?